# How can I make a UIToolbar from a UINavigationController taller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a UINavigationController with a UINavigationBar at the top of the screen and a UIToolbar at the bottom. I want to make the toolbar a bit taller. Here's my code:

```
CGRect toolbarFrame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
toolbarFrame.size.height += 20;
toolbarFrame.origin.y -= 20;
self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;

[self setToolbarItems:@[myButton]];
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

This seems like it should work and doesn't generate any errors/warnings, but the size of the toolbar stays at the defaults.

Is there a way to change the size of a UINavigationController's UIToolbar, or should I just make a custom UIToolbar for this?

Comment: From the docs for [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW24) `Access to this toolbar is provided solely for clients that want to present an action sheet from the toolbar. You should not modify the UIToolbar object directly.`

Comment: @Paul.s I assumed that they were referring to deeper/more functional changes, not simply messing with the appearance. Reading it again, though, you're probably right; they don't specify. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your code and just adjust your code's sequence. It will work:

```
[self setToolbarItems:@[myButton]];
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

CGRect toolbarFrame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
toolbarFrame.size.height += 20;
toolbarFrame.origin.y -= 20;
self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
```

I think this is because `setToolbarItems` will adjust the appearance of your tool bar. So you need firstly do other init-related things. Then adjust its appearance(such change its frame.)